# What are the things to know before to start Game Development Using C++?

Tags: c++

I just want to ask the question above ^. I want to learn C++ language. Someday i want to develop Game Application in c++ and I think it is so difficult for me to achieve that but im willing to learn and achieve that goals for may personal satisfaction and also for my CV as well. Can you give me a guidelines on how to achieve that goals? What are the languages that i need to learn together with c++? please help me.. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know any languages currently? Just because C++ is the industry standard does not mean you need to know it.

Comment: but c++ is the powerful language. I want to start learning c++ before other new language that is used today in game development.

Comment: That argument is stupid. Games can be made in any language. Don't bother wasting time learning C++ because 'it's powerful'.

Comment: I'm just want to know what is the name of the tree to know what is the fruit : )

Comment: @adietan63 Starting with C++ is like starting with formula instead of normal cars. It is possible, but it can be very hard. I recommend you to start with Java, it is much easier :)

Answer (score 3):

You would probably be well served to know quite a bit

**First:** Game programming is easier than it's made out to be, it's not extremely simplistic, however it *is* easy to wrap your head around.

**Second:** C++ doesn't offer graphical abilities right off the bat. There is *nothing* in the standard library that does straight graphical stuff. Therefore you must learn another library/API in order to work with graphics.

**Third:** Be prepared to spend time learning. Be prepared to spend time troubleshooting. Be prepared for crappy programs/games, simply because you don't know better. You will get good with time, dedication, and will power.

**Fourth:** Game programming, and graphical programming in general is *AMAZING!* It's like creating worlds with your fingertips. Nothing is beyond reach.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try to replicate a basic 2d game with libraries like [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).  For example, tetris, arkanoid. These libraries have many tutorials and manuals to do basic ( and less basic ) things. The best form to learn program games is to program games.

I think that c++ is a good language to begin because is not very high level like Java, or Python that abstract some concepts like memory management.

Comment: The GC in Java is lower level than the SBRM in C++, not higher. Just look at the absolute atrocity that is their scheme for dealing with Files and various Streams- it's `free()` all over again.

Comment: @DeadMG: SBRM is a special case. Yes, the Java GC is more low level, but usually we don't use it because it runs behind the scenes. The memory deallocation is then abstracted and the programmer doesn't need to deal with it. Thanks for mentioning SBRM, I never had thinking about this.